# React native webview is not loading in android device

Tags: react-native, d3.js, webview

I am trying to load the graph inside the webview. It is working both in android and iOS simulator. When I was trying to load the same in android device, when the usb is connected to the device it is loading without any error but when the cable is disconnected from the device it is giving the following error Encountered an error loading page.
Error Is :-

> {"canGoForward":false,"code":-6,"canGoBack":false,"description":"net:ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED","loading":false}

I am trying to load the following url

```
const LoacalWebURL = require('./Graphs/polarblock.html');
const LoacalWebURL1 = require('./Localgraph/forced.html');
const LoacalWebURL2 = require('./Localgraph/bump_chart/index.html');

// The web view code where I am trying to load the above url:
 <WebView
     style = {styles.WebViewStyle}
     source={LoacalWebURL1}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     domStorageEnabled={true}
     startInLoadingState={true}
   />

  <WebView
     style = {styles.WebViewStyle}
     source={LoacalWebURL2}
     javaScriptEnabled={true}
     domStorageEnabled={true}
     startInLoadingState={true}
   />
```

Comment: It is a known issue, data from few URL is not loading in webview! Even I am not able to load PDF from my firebase storage

Comment: @RaajNadar I tried for the simple hello world html file and tried to load that in webview. After disconnecting the usb cable from the device i'am getting the same error.